# How can I open Deeplink but not Open with Dialog in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am doing Deeplink in Xamarin. Everything works fine when I open the link like this:

```
private async void _viewmore_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string linkapp = "https://mydomain.me/ProductDetail/1";
    await Browser.OpenAsync(linkapp, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
}
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
protected override async void OnAppLinkRequestReceived(Uri uri)
{
    if (uri.Host.ToLower() == "mydomain.me" && uri.Segments != null && uri.Segments.Length == 3)
    {
        string action = uri.Segments[1].Replace("/", "");
        bool isActionParamsValid = int.TryParse(uri.Segments[2], out int productId);
        if (action == "ProductDetail" && isActionParamsValid)
        {
            if (productId > 0)
            {
                var getProdID = await _apiService.LoadProductID(productId);

                detailProduct = getProdID;

                var detailContentPage = new ProductDetail(detailProduct);
                detailContentPage.BindingContext = detailProduct;

                await MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(detailContentPage);
            }
            else
            {
                // it can be security attack => navigate to home page or login page.
                App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainView(0));
            }
        }
    }

    base.OnAppLinkRequestReceived(uri);
}
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
//Invite App Link
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
              DataScheme = "https",
              DataHost = "mydomain.me",
              DataPathPrefix = "/",
              AutoVerify = true,
              Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
              DataScheme = "http",
              DataHost = "mydomain.me",
              AutoVerify = true,
              DataPathPrefix = "/",
              Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]
```

**(For Android) Create a Digital Assets file named assetlinks.json**

```
[
   {
      "relation":[
         "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
      ],
      "target":{
         "namespace":"android_app",
         "package_name":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "sha256_cert_fingerprints":[
            "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

I uploaded the link: `https://mydomain.me/.well-known/assetlinks.json` -> It's ok

When I execute: `_viewmore_Tapped`. It opens again `Open with`:

[image]

How can it not show the **Open with** dialog box, **I want it to be able to automatically enter My App.**.

I know that the option: Always can be clicked, however I don't want that. Please note that when I select Open with My App it opens fine.

I've searched on google a lot, but I still haven't found a solution for it. Hoping for any help from everyone. Thank you

**Update**

Testing App-Links: `https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site= https://mydomain.me:&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls`. And I found it to be fine

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [Web intent resolution](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#web-intent-resolution)? Follow the link shown in "Verify the domain using Android App Links.". ALSO read the points mentioned in the next few lines after that sentence.

Comment: I have seen that article, however I am still not clear, In the article is about starting from Android version 12 and above. If Android version 8.0.0 then the web intent resolves to the user's default browser app instead? Even though the domain is verified?

Comment: No, in earlier Androids you didn't have to "verify the domain". So it was easier to get it to open your app. The IntentFilters shown in MainActivity should be all you needed on older devices. What Android version did you test in this question?

Comment: I am testing on Android 8.0.0 Samsung Galaxy S8 real machine. The content above is all I have. I have updated enough domains: mydomain.me. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is possible for Android to automatically register an application as the default handler for a URI   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/app-linking

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT - the code shown in question seems to be what is described in that link. Chim is asking whether they have left out something they need to do.

Comment: @ChimDiTru - the link Adrian gave, near the end, Testing App Links, describes ways to verify that everything is correct. Have you done those verifications?

Comment: Yes, Testing App-Links: https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site= https://mydomain.me:&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls. And I found it to be fine. I have updated the above

Comment: I also rebuilt the app, I ran the test and it still says Open with, do I need to clear the app browser or reset the phone settings? haizzz :(

Comment: once you choose the always option, does the dialog box still shows?

Comment: If I choose always in the dialog, next time it won't show the dialog

Comment: As noted in my question. I don't want to show that dialog. Do you have any other comments?

Comment: try the troubleshooting steps in https://help.branch.io/faq/docs/app-does-not-open-directly-gives-an-option-to-choose-between-browser-and-app-android  if not work, try it on other device to see how it works